# getnameinfo -- what's syscall for it in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linux-kernel, system-calls

There's a function https://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo How do I know what the syscall for it is? There's no such a function in Linux syscall table. Or does exist only in that C library?

Comment: The fact that it's section 3 of the manual suggests that it's not a system call. Section 2 is for system calls and section 3 is for C library functions.

Comment: @RossRidge, is that a convention? what is section 1 for?

Comment: `man man` lists the sections, 1 is "Executable programs or shell commands"

Comment: @TrentP, alright. but why doesn't this work "man 2", for example? shouldn't it open the section #2?

Comment: Because they never implemented that. You could try `man 2 intro` or `man -s 2 -k ""` depending on what you were hoping to see.

Comment: When you supply one argument to `man` it assumes that argument is the command you want information about. There is no command called `2`. When you supply two arguments, if the first argument is a number, it is taken to be the section number to restrict the command search, and the second argument the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getnameinfo` has no direct system call. It is a library function that performs a number of activities to fulfill the request. For example, when looking up the host name, it will likely try to:

- consult local files (such as `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `/etc/hosts`)
- find the IP address of its DNS server (read `/etc/resolv.conf`)
- perform socket writes and reads using the DNS protocol to ask for the host name

If you write a simple application using the `getnameinfo` API correctly, you can then use the `strace` utility to find out what system calls are being used. There will be a lot of extra information, but if you study it carefully, you will see the relevant calls being made. A few lines of the relevant output on my system:

```
...
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
...
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("8.8.8.8")}, 16) = 0
...
```

Comment: what's better for an assembly app: to implement it myself or use the C function?

Comment: @Kooiomo When in doubt, use the C function. I recommend you to call into the libc for all system calls and non-trivial library functions for better portability.